# Finding the Inverse of $f(x) = \frac x{2^x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

How does one find the inverse of the equation:

$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{2^x}
$$

for the least possible output value?

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form for the inverse.

Comment: You can't: this function is not onto (for instance, it never takes on the value $1$) and it is not injective (it has the same value at $1$ and at $2$). There is also probably no closed form for the "inverse" (for instance, taking solutions less than $1/\ln(2)$) without using the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** You may write
$$
\frac{x}{2^x}=z
$$ or
$$
-(x\ln 2)\:e^{-(x\ln 2)}=-z \ln 2
$$ then have a look at the Lambert function $W(\cdot)$: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) or [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Answer (score 1):

$$ y = \dfrac{x}{2^x} $$

$$ x = \dfrac{y}{2^y} $$

writing y as a function of x is difficult, if not impossible.